# Ambiguous exception type

Tags: haskell, types, exception

I changed some old code from `Prelude.catch` to `Control.Exception.catch` and got an ambiguous type error. "No big deal", I thought. However, on closer inspection, I'm not exactly sure why this doesn't work as-is...

```
handler :: Exception e => e -> IO x

with_handler :: IO x -> IO x
with_handler act = catch act handler
```

It appears to me that this code ought to *work*, and yet it clearly violates some nominative rule of the type system. (I'm not sure what though.)

Can somebody explain exactly what the type checker is unhappy about?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: "As I said"? You didn't say that. Also, that's not the full error message.

Comment: Here's a reduced version of the code that doesn't involve exceptions: `let foo :: (Read a) => a -> (); foo _ = () in foo (read "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know which type to use for the `handler`. It can't see at runtime what exception is raised and then choose the appropriate type for `handler`, it must resolve the type at compile time.

It might be possible to give `handler` the type

```
handler :: SomeException -> IO x
```

which would resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: So you mean passing `handler` to another function means that the type variable has to be fixed at that moment?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, because within `catch` the handler is monomorphic (otherwise `catch` would have to have the type `IO a -> (forall e. (Exception e) => e -> IO a) -> IO a`).

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid If the type variable is swallowed, yes. If it remains accessible, it can still be resolved later (but must be resolved at compile time anyway).

Comment: So because the type signature for `with_handler` does not mention e0, it must be resolved to a monotype at that call site?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yup, that's the deal with constrained type variables. At the point they disappear from the signature, they must have been resolved.